# Is "The requirement is that it only report once" valid?

Tags: grammaticality

As opposed to "The requirement is that it only reports once"?

What are the grammar terms you would use to describe the reason it's one or the other?

edit: Another option: "The requirement is that it will only report once"

Comment: Since"it" is the singular subject, "report" should be used rather than "reports" which would be plural..

Comment: In this case, annoyingly, both are correct. It's an instance where different interpretations of the same sentence can produce different syntax. *It only report once* uses the subjunctive, while *it only reports once* uses the simple present. If you use the future tense, as in the final example, that's fine too.